# I have bootstrap as the first link and then my custom styles. Yet, this particular tag stays the same. Others all work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This particular h3 tag does not get overridden. I tried using !important. I have seen a different question which is similar but the problem there was that the styles were getting applied to the div. Here I have chosen the correct tag.

```
h3 {
text-align: left;
vertical-align: middle;
color: #333333;
font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 2rem;
font-weight: 400;}
```

Here is a result of the
[computed output and a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tCtL.png).

&

Here is a screenshot for the [rendered styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnUes.png).

Update:

Here is the HTML for the relevant section and I have also added the custom css:

```html
<!-- Sample Task 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row task">
    <div class="col-md-1 centric">
      <i class="black-icon icon ion-ios-circle-outline"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11">
      <h3>
        Solve calculus questions from maths textbook.
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- /Sample Task 1 -->
```

Custom CSS:

```css
.task {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.centric {
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see your html. A screenshot of console computed styles is very helpful too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the immediate support. I wasn't sure what you meant by console computed styles but after some research, I was able to get the screenshot. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that's close to what I'm looking for but not quite. In the bottom right corner of the screenshot you'll see another box; that box shows the styles that are actually applied to the final output. Click the dropdown arrow by the style you are having a problem with and include a screenshot of that. For example, color; you can see in the bottom right corner it is grey, that is the final computed output of color. Also as mentioned, included the relevant section of html.

Comment: Also note that you have 3 errors; click on "Console". What are those?

Comment: I updated the post. The console errors are regarding the icon fonts that I am using. They were woff and ttf that I did not import and that's why it caused 2 errors. The third one is that I am using vue production level. The minified one because my js is sorted.

Comment: Thanks. See the small grey arrow by "color" in the rendered styles? Click on that. That shows us how/why the color grey is applied. It will also show if your custom css is in play at all, why it may be overwritten, etc. Screenshot of that is most helpful.

Comment: 1.2.h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6  This is what it says for all the unwanted styles.

Comment: Please see my answer. In the codepen, the h3 styles in your code are being applied. Is that what you want? I'm not sure if that is your problem or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thank you KayakinKoder for teaching me the debugging technique from chrome. The bootstrap webkit transformation was not getting overridden in the custom h3. So, here is the code that I had to write to override the webkit translation which was not overridden in css. Apparently, webkit translations are rendered after the tags.

Here is the code to override text and div translations:

```css
h3.text-left {
    position: relative;
    top: 45%;
    transform: translateY(-45%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-45%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-45%);
}
```

Comment: *Nothing* about webkit translations or positioning was in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my last comment, a screenshot of the applied styles (e.g. clicking the dropdown by `color`) is about the only way we could help you figure out what style is getting applied and why.

Without that we cannot guess what the other CSS in your project is doing, but here is output of the code you supplied; I've changed `color: #333333;` to `color: blue;` As you can see, the style is applied correctly: the text is blue. https://codepen.io/cpj22/pen/rJRayz

Rereading your question, I'm not actually sure what the perceived problem is. Is it that this h3 tag is *not* getting applied, or that it *is* getting applied?

Comment: The h3 tag is not getting applied. The font width is supposed to be more and the position is supposed to be vertically centered

Comment: Try adding a quick add bootstrap 4. Now what I am saying is that the font is not being aligned properly. The h3 is not properly aligned.

Comment: @ParthAgarwal color gets applied though, right? Change your `color: #333333` to `color: red;` Is the text red? I bet it is. Let me know if the color of the text is red or not when you try this, then we'll go on to the next step depending on whether the color is red or not.

Comment: Yes it turns red. That gets overridden but then the problem was webkit translations. I found the fix with your debugging method. Thanks a ton man!

Comment: @ParthAgarwal cool, if you can accept my answer/upvote that would be appreciated

Comment: I can't. My rep is below 15 and I am new to stack. So, when I tried to upvote, it said my upvote will not be counted. I am really sorry.